# Select duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns like the sample below.

All rows have a unique productid but there are duplicates of customerid and productname together. I want to select only 1 record of each duplicate into a new table with all 3 columns. So from the rows below I want row 1 and 3 into the new table.

```
productid(guid)                        customerid    productname

4362C96D-B413-EA11-A811-000D3A25C7C2   12345678910   credit

C7EC397D-04BF-E611-80EE-005056A027F8   12345678910   credit

F796026C-B413-EA11-A811-000D3A25C942   24681012141   leasing

7490976F-B413-EA11-A811-000D3A25C7C6   24681012141   leasing
```

I use this  SQL to select all the duplicate rows into a new table:

```
SELECT p.productid, p2.customerid, p2.productname
INTO tempTable
FROM products AS p
JOIN (SELECT customerid, productname
      FROM products 
      GROUP BY customerid, productname
      HAVING COUNT(productname)>1) AS p2
ON p.customerid = p2.customerid AND p.productname= p2.productname
ORDER BY p.customerid, p.productname
```

This SQL works without the productid but won't find the duplicates if I add productid that is unique pr row.

```
SELECT customerid, productname 
FROM testtable 
GROUP BY customerid, productname
HAVING COUNT(productname) > 1
ORDER BY customerid

| 12345678910 | credit |
| 24681012141 | leasing |
```

How can I query this data to select only 1 of each duplicate row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable (productid varchar(255),customerid bigint, productname varchar(50))
> INSERT INTO MyTable (productid,customerid,productname) VALUES 
> ('4362C96D-B413-EA11-A811-000D3A25C7C2',12345678910,'credit'),
> ('C7EC397D-04BF-E611-80EE-005056A027F8',12345678910,'credit'),
> ('F796026C-B413-EA11-A811-000D3A25C942',24681012141,'leasing'),
> ('7490976F-B413-EA11-A811-000D3A25C7C6',24681012141,'leasing')
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT 
>       productid,
>       customerid, 
>       productname,
>       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid, productname ORDER BY productid) AS rn
>     FROM MyTable 
> )
>
> SELECT customerid, 
>       productname FROM CTE WHERE rn =1
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  customerid | productname
> ----------: | :----------
> 12345678910 | credit     
> 24681012141 | leasing
> ```

> ```
> SELECT customerid, productname 
> FROM MyTable 
> GROUP BY customerid, productname
> HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
> ORDER BY customerid 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  customerid | productname
> ----------: | :----------
> 12345678910 | credit     
> 24681012141 | leasing
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9235619e4ebdcf9a26e34573ebb9ff85)*

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function to your result set to distinguish between the GUID values.

```
SELECT 
  productid,
  customerid, 
  productname
INTO tempTable
SELECT
  productid,
  customerid, 
  productname
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      productid,
      customerid, 
      productname,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid, productname ORDER BY productid) AS rn
    FROM testtable 
  ) AS d
WHERE d.rn = 1
```